# Interact.jl error: WebIOServer not defined

Tags: julia

I am getting this error when using the Interact.jl @manipulate macro in Juno:

```
UndefVarError: WebIOServer not defined

    enter code here

setup_server() at webio.jl:76
show(::IOContext{Base.GenericIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}}}, ::MIME{Symbol("application/prs.juno.plotpane+html")}, ::Widget{:manipulate,Any}) at webio.jl:68
show(::IOContext{Base.GenericIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}}}, ::String, ::Widget{:manipulate,Any}) at multimedia.jl:109
displayinplotpane(::Widget{:manipulate,Any}) at showdisplay.jl:51
displayandrender(::Widget{:manipulate,Any}) at showdisplay.jl:131
(::Atom.var"#208#213"{String})() at eval.jl:136
#invokelatest#1 at essentials.jl:712 [inlined]
invokelatest at essentials.jl:711 [inlined]
macro expansion at dynamic.jl:24 [inlined]
eval(::String, ::Int64, ::String, ::String, ::Bool) at eval.jl:113
invokelatest(::Any, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{,Tuple{}}}) at essentials.jl:712
invokelatest(::Any, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at essentials.jl:711
macro expansion at eval.jl:41 [inlined]
(::Atom.var"#188#189")() at task.jl:358
```

- Piece of code (the function generatePlot is defined previously for generating Makie plots):

```
@manipulate for variable = Dict(string(vars[i])=>vars[i] for i=1:16),
                labl = Dict(string(label[i])=>label[i] for i=1:length(label))
                generatePlot(variable, labl)
end
```

Env:

```
  [c601a237] Interact v0.10.3
  [ee78f7c6] Makie v0.11.0
  [85f8d34a] NCDatasets v0.10.2
  [2913bbd2] StatsBase v0.33.0
  [0f1e0344] WebIO v0.8.14
```

Any thoughts on what can be the problem?